# Help with a logarithm proof

Tags: logarithms

If $$\log \frac {1} {2}  (a + b) =  \frac {1} {2}(\log (a) + \log (b) )$$ Prove that 
$$ (a + b)^2  = 4ab $$

Can anyone show me how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Didi you try anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$2 \ln \left(\frac{1}{2} (a + b)\right) = \ln a + \ln b$$

$$\ln \left(\frac{1}{4} (a+b)^2\right) = \ln (ab)$$

$$(a+b)^2 = 4ab$$

Comment: I'll just add that you can go from the second line to the third because $ln(x)$ is an injective function.

Comment: @F.A. yes, a useful remark

Comment: How did you go from $ \frac {1} {2} (a+b) $ to $ \frac {1} {4} (a+b)^2 $ ?

Comment: @Jimmy because of the identity $a \ln b = \ln (b^a)$

Comment: Okay I see. Thank you.

Comment: @Jimmy you're welcome!